# Memory Management Issue with copy in connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am passing the _resultArray object which is in connectionDidFinishLoading using delegate from one class to another class  through this delegate method.I am releasing in dealloc but i am not sure that it is ok.How to release this _resultArray..

Here is my code..

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSString *urlDataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:receiveData 
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *soapDictionary = nil;
    soapDictionary = [parser objectWithString:urlDataString error:&error];
    resultArray = [soapDictionary copy];
    [urlDataString release];
    [self soapResultSurvey:resultArray];
}

//Delegate Method
-(void)soapResultSurvey:(id)_resultSurvey{
    [delegate soapResultSurvey:_resultSurvey];
}
```

Comment: It depends on what are you doing in the delegate method "soapResultSurvey. Can you show us the delegate code method ?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resultArray = [[soapDictionary copy] autorelease];
```

then remember that resultArray will be deallocated later at the end of the thread, so if your delegate need to retain it, well, do it there, in your delegate soapResultSurvey: method